# enabling adfs in a server which is already joined a domain

Tags: adfs

I am trying to setup a ADFS4.0 server for exploration on OIDC with ADFS.
Is it possible to add adfs role to a server which is already joined to an existing domain?

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you see any problem with it? I would say, it is mandatory to have your server joined to an existing domain, you would not be able to install ADFS otherwise.

Comment: Hi @Vijay, was the answer below useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it is mandatory to have your AD FS server joined to an existing domain, you would not be able to install it otherwise.

You can see all the requirements here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/design/ad-fs-requirements#BKMK_4

There is **Domain Requirements** section which states:

> - All AD FS servers must be a joined to an AD DS domain.
> - All AD FS servers within a farm must be deployed in a single domain.
> - The domain that the AD FS servers are joined to must trust every user
>     account domain that contains users authenticating to the AD FS
>     service.